# Series convergence value

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

Find a real number $A>0$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n!}{(cn)^n}$ converges if $c > A$ and diverges if $c < A$.

I started by performing the ratio test. From that I deduced that $c$ would have to be some sort of fraction for it to satisfy the problem's conditions. However, I'm unsure about how to continue the problem to find the value of $A$. Could I have some help?

Comment: How did you simplify if to $1/c^n$?

Comment: In my calculations the ratio test would give $\frac{(n+1)!/(c(n+1)^{n+1})}{n!/(cn)^n}$, which simplified to $\frac{c^{-1}}{(1+1/n)^n}$, which goes to $1/(ce)$, now just check what the ratio test says about how this limit determines convergence/divergence.

Comment: I got it! Thank you so much!